# select unique values in one column and match with the criteria in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

need to group the table below (1) into ouput table (2) These are sample values, in real they're corresponding numbers and code. The id should be unique and code should match the criteria ( if only xz exists then xz; if xz and xy exists then select only xy  and so on) Tried 'if exists' and 'case when..then'  but not luck so far, since both column have PK . I use SQL Server 2008, thanks

```
 id   code
101   xz
102   xz
102   xy
103   xz
103   xa

output
101  xz
102  xy
103  xa
```

Comment: You are more likely to get help if you post some code you attempted and how it failed to work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study [**Ranking functions**](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=rank%20sql%20server%202008&oq=rank%20sql%20ser&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.4545j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) , they are of great help in grouping queries.

```
WITH cte AS
(

SELECT id,code,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY code) as row
FROM tableName
)

SELECT id,code
FROM cte
WHERE row=1
```